# Javascript string undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I have a code like this:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script language="javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
            for(i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
                var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
                x.setAttribute("type", "button");
                x.setAttribute("value", String.fromCharCode(i + 65));
                x.setAttribute("id", String.fromCharCode(i + 65));
                x.setAttribute("onclick", "isTOF(self.id)");
                document.body.appendChild(x);
            }
        }

        function isTOF(v) {
            alert(v);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I wanted to make it alert its own alphabet(value), but it doesn't work.

So for example, when I click A Button, the program should alert 'A'.

But it alerts 'undefined'.

I don't know what the problem is.

I want to make my code work properly.

How can I make it?

Comment: What do you think `self.id` is?

Comment: @tkausl self.id should be button's own alphabet. So for example, when I click C button, its id is C, and self.id is C. So, when isTOF function runs, v == C. But now it doesn't work like that.

Comment: It doesn't work because `self` doesn't exist

Comment: @tkausl Oh, thank you so much. But why `self` doesn't exist?

Comment: Why would it exist? You never declared a variable with that name

Comment: @HoseongJeon JavaScript doesn't use `self` for that. You might be confusing it with another programming language.

Comment: But it looks like `this.id` will work ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are having is caused by `self` not being defined. Instead, you should use the value that you already set, and pass in `this` to `isTOF`:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script language="javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
            for(i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
                var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
                x.setAttribute("type", "button");
                x.setAttribute("value", String.fromCharCode(i + 65));
                x.setAttribute("id", String.fromCharCode(i + 65));
                x.setAttribute("onclick", "isTOF(this)");
                document.body.appendChild(x);
            }
        }

        function isTOF(v) {
            alert(v.value);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

This way, you are passing a reference to the element to `isTOF` in case you want to do anything with it or just for purely information purposes.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @HoseongJeon glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is:

```
x.setAttribute("onclick", "isTOF(self.id)");
```

There's no variable named `self` in scope at that point. Perhaps you meant to use `this`, which would work:

```js
for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
  var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
  x.setAttribute("type", "button");
  x.setAttribute("value", String.fromCharCode(i + 65));
  x.setAttribute("id", String.fromCharCode(i + 65));
  x.setAttribute("onclick", "isTOF(this.id)");
  document.body.appendChild(x);
}

function isTOF(v) {
  alert(v);
}
```

But since you have a direct reference to the element already, rather than assign a *string attribute* in the HTML to be turned into a handler (which is basically `eval` in the form of an HTML attribute), it would be better to attach the listener properly using Javascript - which will make things easier, because then the `id`, if you set a variable to it beforehand, can simply be referenced again in the handler, rather than having to check `this.id`. In addition, you can often use dot notation rather than `setAttribute`, which is more concise and easier to read, so it's probably preferable in most cases:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
  const x = document.createElement("INPUT");
  x.type = 'button';
  const id = String.fromCharCode(i + 65);
  x.value = id;
  x.id = id;
  x.onclick = () => isTOF(id);
  document.body.appendChild(x);
}

function isTOF(v) {
  console.log(v);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use an event listener instead like so:

```js
function isTOF(e) {
    console.log("id:["+ this.id +"], value:["+ this.value +"]");
}
window.onload = function() {
    for(i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
        x.setAttribute("type", "button");
        x.setAttribute("value", String.fromCharCode(i + 65));
        x.setAttribute("id", String.fromCharCode(i + 65));
        x.addEventListener("click", isTOF, false);
        document.body.appendChild(x);
    }
}
```